# I am using rails-bootstrap-forms gem with devise form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails-bootstrap-forms gem with devise.
How i can customize form_tag with bootstrap with gem rails-bootstrap-forms.
My code is

```
<%= form_tag topic_posts_path(@topic) do %>
    <%= render 'form' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Create post' %>

<%end%>
```

and my partial _form is

```
    <h2>Create new post</h2>


    <%= label :post, :description %>
    <%= text_area :post, :description %>
```

I want something like

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="xyz">xyz</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="xyz" placeholder="Enter xyz">
  </div>
```

any help ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to customize form with bootstrap.

Comment: What do you want to customize? Why doesn't the above code work for you? What is the problem?

Comment: actually i want to give it a nicer look same as like my previous post's code

Comment: Then again, post the generated HTML and post the HTML that you expect.

Comment: @Hao I dont know how exactly to tell u html code but i need my view to enclose with <div class="form-group"></div> of Bootstrap  but i am trying it check edits

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to have input fields wrapped with `<div class="form-group">...</div>`. Replace `form_tag` with `bootstrap_form_for`. Replace `text_area` with `f.text_area`. That's how you already got [your signup form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312101/devise-customization-issue-with-rails-bootstrap-forms) work.

Comment: giving error undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for :description:Symbol in line <%= f.text_area :post, :description %>

Comment: Use <%= f.text_area :description %>

Comment: If i am using <%= f.text_area :description %> its not creating Post